# does an accelerated charge would be slower relative to an neutral particle due to radiating and lose energy ? both in free fall

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, particle-physics, charge, classical-electrodynamics

this part from this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_of_a_charge_in_a_gravitational_field

"Putting together these two basic facts of general relativity and electrodynamics, we seem to encounter a paradox. For if we dropped a neutral particle and a charged particle together in a gravitational field, the charged particle should begin to radiate as it is accelerated under gravity, thereby losing energy, and slowing relative to the neutral particle. Then a free-falling observer could distinguish free fall from true absence of forces, because a charged particle in a free-falling laboratory would begin to be pulled relative to the neutral parts of the laboratory, even though no obvious electric fields were present."

I can't get it at all, any explanations please?

Comment: Actually even without trying to understand all the physics at once in that article, I can't even understand the punch line! Does it, or doesn't it, or is it actually still a point of contention these days? I can't even understand if Feynman says it does or doesn't.

Comment: Whether Feynman's conjecture is true or not, there is no paradox. As they clearly state in the Wikipedia article it is a false paradox. What does the question concern? The resolution of the paradox, or the (incorrect) argument for the paradox in the first place?

Comment: Who tells us that a neutron does not emit radiation during a deceleration or deflection? Your question seems to be a perfect statement that both the charged particle and the neutron have to radiate.

Comment: To apply the equivalence principle to a free falling charge, you need to put in  a conducting object and consider dropping that system in a gravitational field. In that case there will be no radiation emitted inside the object. But if you just drop the charge in a gravitational field then the equivalence principle doesn't apply because the radiation is due to non-local effects, the way the fields behave at infinity is then going to be relevant here.